Jetpack animation snapTo inside LaunchedEffect is not soon enough, wonky lifecycle
Using this code to show a paginated graph, when the page changes the entire graph is rendered for a frame and then I get my animation starting from zero. I think this is because the code inside LaunchedEffect doesn't take effect until the next render pass and the remember on the animatable is remembering the previous page's value. How can I prevent this flashing effect?
@Composable
fun AnimateList(points: List<DataPoints>): List<DataPoints> {
    val animatable = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    LaunchedEffect(points) {
        animatable.snapTo(0f)
        animatable.animateTo(
            points.size.toFloat(),
            animationSpec = tween(1000),
        )

    }
    return points.take(animatable.value.toInt())
}


Check that LaunchedEffect has taken place after the input param has changed like so:
@Composable
fun AnimateList(
    points: List<DataPoints>,
): List<DataPoints> {
    val animatable = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    val first = remember { mutableStateOf(points.firstOrNull()) }
    LaunchedEffect(points) {
        animatable.snapTo(0f)
        animatable.animateTo(
            points.size.toFloat(),
            animationSpec = tween(1000),
        )
        first.value = points.firstOrNull()
    }

    // to prevent a 'flash' defect:
    // make sure LaunchedEffect has run each time points changes
    return if (first.value != points.firstOrNull()) {
        return emptyList()
    } else {
        points.take(animatable.value.toInt())
    }
}

